# SSRS VBA code Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: excel, vba, visual-studio, reporting-services

I have some custom code in an SSRS report which works perfectly well (with minor changes) when I run it with test data in Excel VBA but fails in SSRS with the error 
**The Value expression for the textbox ‘textbox72’ contains an error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object**
The report is a simple table report. The custom code compares "before" and "after" strings in an audit report and should send back added or removed details. The strings are separated by char(10). The strings lines can only be added or removed. The string lines themselves will not change. There are no Null strings. I have successfully tested this in Excel VBA, so I think the code is probably ok. Any ideas?

The code call in textbox72 is

```
=iif(len(Fields!AOS.Value) > 0 and len(Fields!AfterAOS.Value) > 0,code.go_compare(ReportItems),"")
```

The code in the report is:

```
Function go_compare(Items as ReportItems) as string
Dim j As Integer
Dim x As Integer
Dim Diff(50) As String
Dim DiffInd As Integer
Dim Intmatch As Integer
Dim StrDiff as string
Dim Arr() As String
Dim Arr1() As String
Dim StrVal As String
Dim StrFinal As String
Dim y As Integer
Dim Str1 as string
Dim Str2 as string

Str1 =  items("AOS_1").value
Str2 = items("AfterAOS").value
StrFinal = ""
StrDiff = ""

For y = 0 To 1
   Erase Diff
   If y = 1 Then
      StrVal = "Removed"
      Arr = Split(Str1, Chr(10))
      Arr1 = Split(Str2, Chr(10))
      Else
      StrVal = "Added"
      Arr = Split(Str2, Chr(10))
      Arr1 = Split(Str1, Chr(10))
  End If
  For j = 0 To UBound(Arr)
    Intmatch = 0
    For x = 0 To UBound(Arr1)
       If Trim(Arr(j)) = Trim(Arr1(x)) Then
         Intmatch = 1
       End If
    Next x
    If Intmatch = 0 Then
      Diff(DiffInd) = Trim(Arr(j))
      DiffInd = DiffInd + 1
    End If
  Next j

  StrDiff = StrDiff & StrVal & " Values" + vbCrLf
  For j = 0 To UBound(Diff)
     If Diff(j) = "" Then Exit For
     StrDiff = StrDiff + Diff(j) + vbCrLf
 Next j
 If Len(StrDiff) > 16 Then
    StrFinal = StrFinal + StrDiff
 End If
 StrDiff = ""
Next y
Return StrFinal
End Function
```

Sample data (from Excel VBA test)

```
Dim StrStr1 As String
Dim StrStr2 As String

 StrStr1 = "xxxx" & Chr(10)
 StrStr1 = StrStr1 & "yyyy" & Chr(10)
 StrStr1 = StrStr1 & "zzzz" & Chr(10)
 StrStr1 = StrStr1 & "aaaa" & Chr(10)
 StrStr1 = StrStr1 & "bbbb" & Chr(10)
 StrStr1 = StrStr1 & "cccc" & Chr(10)
StrStr1 = StrStr1 & "dddd" & Chr(10)

StrStr2 = "xxxx" & Chr(10)
StrStr2 = StrStr2 & "yyyy" & Chr(10)
StrStr2 = StrStr2 & "zzzz" & Chr(10)
StrStr2 = StrStr2 & "aaaa" & Chr(10)
StrStr2 = StrStr2 & "bbbb" & Chr(10)
StrStr2 = StrStr2 & "dddd" & Chr(10)
StrStr2 = StrStr2 & "eeee" & Chr(10)
```

Expected result

```
Removed Values
cccc

Added Values
eeee
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but I notice in `code.go_compare(ReportItems)` that `ReportItems` is a type name you use in `Function go_compare(Items as ReportItems)`

Comment: Thanks @PaulOgilvie. I have tried variants on this where I send fields individually rather than the whole report item collection but still get the same error e.g. `=code.go_compare(Fields!AOS.Value,Fields!AfterAOS.Value)` (plus changing the code to reflect this)

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to have arisen from the Erase Diff statement. If I follow this with a ReDim of the array then the routine works!

Anyone out there know why the original code (i.e. without the ReDim) might work in Excel VBA but not in SSRS?

```
For y = 0 To 1
    Erase Diff
    Redim Diff(100)
```